# Пароль для входа в jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, password

Помогите пожалуйста, когда я запускаю jupyter notebook, мне предлагается ввести пароль. Я помню в самый первый раз мне пришлось скопировать его из ссылки. 
Всегда при запуске юпитера после этого он заходил без пароля! А теперь он словно его сбросил
Теперь я не помню этот пароль и соответственно не могу зайти. 
Я очень плохо понимаю, что происходит. Я искала решение в интернете, я пробовала переустановить юпитер и анаконду ни ничего не помогает! 
Где мне сбросить пароль? Пожалуйста, помогите, я в отчаянии! И пишите как для очень тупых людей, я вообще не понимаю что делать и совершенно не разбираюсь в этом! Во всех ответах люди пишут какие-то команды, где мне их вводить? 
Или хотя бы как удалить всю эту анаконду с компа полностью, чтобы загрузить её заново и заново зарегистрироваться?

Answer (score 1):

Для всех кто сталкивается с этой проблемой:

1. открыть терминал
2. ввести команду jupyter notebook password
3. установите новый пароль(его не должно быть видно)
4. повторить новый пароль(его тоже не должно быть видно)
5. для тех кто пользуется анакондой ввести anaconda-navigator
6. выбрать нужный инструмент
7. ввести новый пароль

вот ссылка
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2971#issuecomment-338951272